# Trying to use SQL DATEADD function to display last 7 days but starting from yesterday

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to tweak my query so it displays the last 7 days of day but starting from yesterday's date not from todays date. I have tried but cant seem to figure it out. Below is the code and I have attached a picture of the output.

```
`SELECT CAST(DATE AS VARCHAR(32)) AS Date , COUNT(UNID) AS Count
FROM
(SELECT UNID, CAST([MSG_DATE_TIME] AS DATE) AS DATE
FROM [ICHNTRIE].[dbo].[MSG_JOURNAL]
WHERE SYSTEM = 'epCernerADTSIUHL7In'
AND MSG_PAYLOAD LIKE '%ADT^A31%'
AND MSG_DATE_TIME >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())) G
GROUP BY G.DATE[enter image description here][1]`
```

Comment: If you take your expression `DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())` out of the query and run it by itself, what value does it generate? Is that the correct value according to your goal? Answer - no. That is why your query does not work. And, of course, you did not limit the query to ignore rows from the current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the date logic you want is:

```
MSG_DATE_TIME < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND
MSG_DATE_TIME >= DATEADD(day, -7, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

One of the "tricks" in SQL Server is remembering that `GETDATE()` does not return just a date; it has a time component as well.  That can throw off date/time comparisons.  Fortunately, it is easy to deal with this by converting the value to a `date`.

Comment: If this is code from a sql stored procedure I find it's usually beneficial to create a variable and use that throughout instead of repeatingly using getdate().

Comment: @sTTu That has the downside of preventing parameter sniffing, effectively the same as `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN`